# How to add 20px to the top when it scrolls down

Tags: javascript

I created a button and when clicked it's scroll down to the next section of the page.

```js
scroll(el) {
  el.scrollIntoView({ 
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'start' 
  });
}
```

```html
<span class="btn"><a (click)="scroll(forecast)">CheckForecast</a</span>
<div #forecast class="container-fluid">
```

Now, when it scrolls down, the top of the section get hided behind the fixed top navBar. I need to compensate the hight of my top navBar for it to scroll all the way down!?

Thanks guys.

Comment: can u show your all html

Comment: Are you using some kind of HTML pre-processor, as that HTML isn't valid at all. The JS is also presumably missing the `function` keyword

Comment: This is a Angular 2 project and this HTML is the only bit related to this scroll function. The fact is that the scroll works but it scrolls 20px too deep. I need to compensate it so won't hide my top content!

Comment: Provide a minimal working exmaple please so that people may work with your snippet. It will help you to get a better response.

Comment: If you are using angular, why did you tag [jquery] and if you use somehow both please add the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the fact that your HTML and JS is totally wrong. Here is a solution, that you may need to fit your needs but is working and very simple:

```js
function scrollto(elna) {
  let el = document.getElementById(elna);
  el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

```html
<span class="btn"><a onclick="scrollto('forecast')">CheckForecast</a></span>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div id="forecast" class="container-fluid">Some forecast</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

The br-tags are only there to have some space and to see any effect at all.

But to make some remarks. If you provide a snippet make sure that there aren't any syntactic errors. 
Your opening a-tag is missing, the keyword function is missing and you haven't included angular in your snippet.

To make it fit to angular you'll need to find out how you get the needed reference to your element. There are plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. Really helping. Now if I need to add those 20px to the top?

Comment: // add a smooth scroll to element
  scroll(el) {
    el.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'start'
   });
   setTimeout(() => {
    window.scrollBy(0, -40);
    }, 500);
  }

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks anyway @sascha10000

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that worked for me at the end:

```
scroll(el) {
el.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth',
  block: 'start'});

setTimeout(() => {
window.scrollBy(0, -40);
}, 500);}
```